# What's the optimal method to use for this database Modeling/Design?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm writing a program for kitchen/recipe management. As of now, the program can add new ingredients to the database. My next step is to add new recipes to the database, using the ingredients.

Since each recipe will have multiple ingredients, and an unlimited number of which can be added to a recipe, creating a separate column for each ingredient selected wouldn't be efficient (I'm assuming).

So the method I've come up with to store the ingredient selections is:

1. Add a recipe_ingredients column to the recipe table in the db, and store the name of each ingredient in 1 single (text) field, separated by commas (CSV style).
2. Write a PHP script to store the list of recipe_ingredients into an array.
3. Do the same for all other attributes (recipe_ingredients_serving_size, recipe_ingredients_calories, etc.)

**So the question is:** Is this method optimal, and if not, what's a better way to go about this?

Comment: None of your apporaches are good. Instead, read up on [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple N:M(many-to-many) relationship, and your approach that you've laid out will likely spell out disaster in terms of efficiency and management.

---

**Here is your situation:**

- You have two entities: `recipes` and `ingredients`.
- **One** ingredient may be a part of **many** recipes.
- **One** recipe may be made up of **many** ingredients.

Whenever you have this relationship between any two entities, you are going to want to have not two, but three tables:

```
+-----------+     +-------------------------+     +-------------------+
| recipes   |     | recipes_has_ingredients |     | ingredients       |
+-----------+     +-------------------------+     +-------------------+
| recipe_id |     | recipe_id               |     | ingredient_id     |
| name      |     | ingredient_id           |     | name              |
| ...       |     +-------------------------+     | calories          |
+-----------+                                     +-------------------+
```

`recipes` and `ingredients` are what's known as *base tables*, where they store intrinsic information about that particular entity.

The `recipes_has_ingredients` table is what's known as a *cross-reference table* (or "XREF"), which stores the ***associations*** between the two entities. The fields in this table: `recipe_id` and `ingredient_id` both link to their respective base tables, and the combination of the two in each row in the XREF table is unique. It basically maps the many associations that each `recipe_id` may have to different `ingredient_id`'s and vice versa.

Why does this design facilitate many-to-many relationships? Because data in that XREF table is allowed to look like this:

```
+-----------------------------+
| recipe_id  |  ingredient_id |
+-----------------------------+
| 1          |  1             |
| 1          |  2             |
| 1          |  3             |
| 2          |  1             |
| 2          |  2             |
| 2          |  3             |
| 3          |  1             |
| 3          |  2             |
| 3          |  3             |
+-----------------------------+
```

As you can clearly see: One recipe is associated with many(3) ingredients, and one ingredient is associated with many(3) recipes. Also notice how values in either of the columns are allowed to repeat, but that the ***combination*** of the two columns is unique — this is really the key aspect of this design that makes the N:M relationship work.

So here are some simple examples of how you can easily retrieve and manage data using this design:

```
// Given a particular recipe_id, retrieve all ingredients used in that recipe:   

SELECT     name
FROM       recipes_has_ingredients
INNER JOIN ingredients USING (ingredient_id)
WHERE      recipe_id = <id>
```

---

```
// Retrieve the name of recipe (of id 4), and total amount of calories it has:

SELECT      a.name, 
            SUM(c.calories) AS calorie_count
FROM        recipes a
INNER JOIN  recipes_has_ingredients b ON a.recipe_id = b.recipe_id
INNER JOIN  ingredients c ON b.ingredient_id = c.ingredient_id
WHERE       a.recipe_id = 4
GROUP BY    a.recipe_id, 
            a.name
```

---

```
// Given a list of ingredient_id's, retrieve all recipes that contain 
// ALL of the listed ingredients

SELECT     name
FROM       recipes
INNER JOIN recipes_has_ingredients USING (recipe_id)
WHERE      ingredient_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY   recipe_id
HAVING     COUNT(*) = 3
```

---

```
// Given a particular recipe_id (id 6), add two more ingredients 
// that it has (ids 4 & 9):

INSERT INTO recipes_has_ingredients VALUES (6,4), (6,9);
```

---

```
// Delete a particular recipe:

DELETE FROM recipe WHERE recipe_id = 4
```

^ The above `DELETE` operation also deletes all of that recipe's associations if you've properly defined the CASCADE rules between your relationships.

---

Looking back at your original design, what if you wanted to update or delete certain ingredients that a recipe has, or how about change the name of an ingredient? You would need hacky procedural code to modify the right positions in csv strings, or you would need to update every row in the table to reflect even the slightest changes in a single ingredient.

There are also many more compelling questions you could answer that you couldn't really otherwise using your original design such as:

- Recipe with highest/lowest calorie count?
- Ingredient that is contained by the most recipes?

...The list goes on, and the benefits of implementing this design will serve you well. You will prevent yourself from a great deal of hardship and suffering by doing things the right way. =)

Comment: EEEEEXCELLENT INFO, ZANE!  thanks!  i'm gonna have to print that out and study it :)

Comment: ^^^thanks so much!  yea, i'm new enough at this (programming) to still make horrific newbie mistakes...but with just enough experience at this point to realize the mistakes before i make them (well...the really bad ones, anyway lol).  i figured it wasn't kosher, so thought i'd post here and get some direction.  thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** the ideal approach to solving this problem.

Comma-separating values in a column makes those values pretty useless - querying for recipes by ingredient would be painful if you just concatenate a bunch of ingredients together into a single string.

Also, how would you relate a single ingredients' calorie count to an ingredient if you're storing them as comma-separated strings?

The ideal solution would be to create a new table for ingredients, and store the name and associated information in that table.. e.g.

```
ingredients
-----------
id 
name
num_calories
```

There are many recipes with many ingredients, so create a table that links ingredients to a particular recipe, this makes the ingredients to recipes relationship many to one to many rather than a straight many to many.

```
recipe_ingredients
------------------
recipe_id
ingredient_id
```

You should read up on [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) here.

Comment: thanks for the quick response!  i already have a separate table for ingredients.  but i'm confused as to how to link the ingredients selected to the recipes as they are created, without having to create a new column for each recipe_ingredient.  not sure if that makes sense, lol

Comment: It looks like these tables would also need quantities. For the ingredients table, you'd need 1) the quantity of the ingredient that has that number of calories, and 2) the units that the quantity is expressed in. For the recipe_ingredients table, you'd need the quantity that's in the recipe, expressed in the same units as in the ingredients table.

Comment: recipe_ingredients has one row for each ingredient in each recipe. For example, if the recipe with ID 6 has 10 ingredients, then recipe_ingredients would have 10 rows with recipe_id 6, one for each ingredient. This may sound cumbersome, but it's a very flexible way to store information, and mysql can handle tables with millions of rows without slowing down much.

Comment: @octern but wouldn't that require a separate table for each recipe?  rather than a separate row for each recipe?  i'm confused, lol.

Comment: No, just one table. When you want to show recipe #6, you query recipe_ingredients for every row where recipe_id=6. You get back 10 rows, one with each ingredient, and put those together into the recipe that you display. On a different page, if you want to display recipe 8, you'd query the same table but get all the rows where recipe_id = 8.